# What is the best way to allow user Edit one Form?

Tags: 7, entities, performance

I want to make a dynamic website using Drupal 7 that allow user to edit any part of the site

this site has more than 10 pages each page has a different content and structure

should I make a content type to each page and add one node to each cck and give permission to site admin to edit this node

Or there is another way (I don't want to make a lot of cck because it make a lot of tables in database) also I need to edit only

I want the best way to make it

Thanks

Comment: I'm not completely sure of your expected outcome here.  It might be worth re-writing the question so that it makes a bit more sense.

Comment: Form edit ? You mean to say he can add/remove fields or just be allowed to submit form ?

Comment: @Chapabu I edit the question is there is something not clear

Comment: @Kantu User can edit only content not remove or add field just edit content

Comment: It sounds to me like you just want to create ten pieces of content and lay them out differently, yes?

Comment: yes ten different content type (structure and data)

Comment: You don't need ten content types.  You can achieve this easily with Panels and one content type!  There are loads of tutorials for panels, just hit up Google.

Comment: I found a solution thanks a lot, I can make a custom form and save data as a variable in database.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is primarily about how to allow the user to edit a form (as the title suggests), then I think the way to go is

1. Create a new role at /admin/people/permissions/roles and call is something like 'editor'.
2. Then go into the permissions page at /admin/people/permissions and give the new role 'Edit any content' permissions under the 'Node' section for each of the content types you have.

If you're simply wondering whether all those content types are OK, I'd say that having 10 content types for a Drupal site is not that crazy or unusual.  Of course, if you're just trying to distinguish the pages from each other in some way, sometimes tagging/taxonomy is better than putting them in different content types, but that depends on what you're trying to achieve.  If they legitimately have different fields/structure, than you're OK to have 10 content types.

Does that answer your questions or were you getting at something else?

Comment: I found a solution thanks a lot, I can make a custom form and save data as a variable in database